# Eclipse JDT AST Parser does not resolve type in Java lambda Expression

Tags: java, lambda, eclipse-jdt

I am using the Eclipse JDT AST Parser (3.10.0) to parse various source code Files.

This is how i initalize the parser:

```
ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS8);
parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);
parser.setBindingsRecovery(true);
parser.setResolveBindings(true);
parser.setStatementsRecovery(true);
parser.setSource(source.toCharArray());
parser.setUnitName(filename);
parser.setEnvironment(classPath.toArray(new String[classPath.size()]), sources, new String[]{"UTF-8"}, true);
final CompilationUnit cu = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);
```

The classpath is created by maven dependency plugin.

This works very well for most Expressions, but it seems to have problems with lambda Expressions

```
Optional<Address> first = adr.stream().filter(
    a -> a.getId().longValue() == contactAddress.getAddressId().longValue()
).findFirst();
```

Evaluating both sides of the comparison each type resolves to `null`. Parsing the same code without the surrounding lambda Expression results in `long` on each side.

Is there any way to as well resolve bindngs in lambda Expressions?

Comment: Could you please try with a recent version of JDT. At the time of 3.10.0 support for lambda expressions was quite fresh. Additionally, you might want to check if the lambda itself has the expected bindings.

Comment: @StephanHerrmann 3.10.0 seems to be the newest version in the maven repo for org.eclipse.jdt:org.eclipse.jdt.core. Has the Group or Artifact Id changed with higher versions?

Comment: JDT was never "officially" pushed to maven central. All version you find there have been uploaded by some "hobbyists" :). The latest official artifact can be found in https://repo.eclipse.org/content/groups/eclipse/ (it's 3.12.0.v20160516-2131, soon to be superseded by 3.12.1, whereas 3.13.0 artifacts are milestone builds).

Comment: @StephanHerrmann has pushed JDT to maven central. See his Blog post. https://objectteams.wordpress.com/2017/01/09/eclipse-neon-2-is-on-maven-central/ use this version: https://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.eclipse.jdt%7Corg.eclipse.jdt.core%7C3.12.2%7Cjar