# Eclipse Jdt type bindings not resolved in lambda expressions

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-jdt

I am running into a similar issue from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39452906/eclipse-jdt-ast-parser-does-not-resolve-type-in-java-lambda-expression) where type bindings within lambda expressions are not being resolved properly for `MethodInvocation` types.

Currently using version '3.13.50' and tried with '3.13.100' which is what Eclipse 4.7.3 seems to use.  Happy to try any debugging; currently stumped because other type bindings resolve correctly (for `ImportDeclaration` statements and for expressions not enclosed in lambda expressions).

---

Parser setup code (`parserClasspath` contains paths to root of all third party library classes (including domain objects whose type bindings need to be resolved), `parserSourcepath` contains the root of the project source files):

```
    char[] sourceInput = source.get().toCharArray();

    ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS9);
    parser.setEnvironment(parserClasspath, parserSourcepath, null, false);
    parser.setResolveBindings(true);
    parser.setBindingsRecovery(true);
    parser.setSource(sourceInput);
    parser.setUnitName(projFilepath);

    return parser.createAST(null);
```

Parser transformer snippet (using ASTVisitor):

```
@Override
public boolean visit(MethodInvocation mi) {
    if (mi.getExpression() != null) {

        // resolves to null when 'mi' is within lambda functions
        ITypeBinding typeBinding = mi.getExpression().resolveTypeBinding();

        if (typeBinding != null) {
            // do stuff
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Example to parse:

```
private DomainType getMockDomainType() {
    DomainType mock = mock(DomainType.class);
    Supplier<DomainType> domainTypeSupplier = () -> {
        DomainType domainType = mock(DomainType.class);
        when(domainType.method()).thenReturn("VALUE");
        ...
        return domainType;
    };

    DomainType domainType = domainTypeSupplier.get();

    when(mock.method()).thenReturn(domainType)
    ...
    return mock;
}
```

Expected output (`method()` will be transformed to `NEW_METHOD()`):

```
private DomainType getMockDomainType() {
    DomainType mock = mock(DomainType.class);
    Supplier<DomainType> domainTypeSupplier = () -> {
        DomainType domainType = mock(DomainType.class);
        when(domainType.NEW_METHOD()).thenReturn("VALUE");
        ...
        return domainType;
    };

    DomainType domainType = domainTypeSupplier.get();

    when(mock.NEW_METHOD()).thenReturn(domainType)
    ...
    return mock;
}
```

Actual output:

```
private DomainType getMockDomainType() {
    DomainType mock = mock(DomainType.class);
    Supplier<DomainType> domainTypeSupplier = () -> {
        DomainType domainType = mock(DomainType.class);
        when(domainType.method()).thenReturn("VALUE");
        ...
        return domainType;
    };

    DomainType domainType = domainTypeSupplier.get();

    when(mock.NEW_METHOD()).thenReturn(domainType)
    ...
    return mock;
}
```

In the `visit(MethodDeclaration mi)` method within the lambda expression for `domainType.method()`, `mi.getExpression().resolveTypeBinding()` is `null` when it should be a binding for `DomainType`.

Comment: This is too vague. Show us your code and an example of what you are parsing, what you get and what you expected to get.

Comment: Is this sufficient?  Or do you need more run-time information?